# How to start app or script after system update

Tags: updates, scripts

I would like to start my script after or during every Ubuntu update. For example:

If I make command sudo apt-get upgrade, I want to start my script after successful update. Same if I make update through Software Updater. Is it possible?

Comment: After successful update or successful upgrade?

Answer (score 2):

### How to start app or script after system *upgrade*

Watch for changes in `/var/log/apt/history.log`:

```
sudo inoticoming /var/log/apt/ upgrade_success {} \;
```

Script `upgrade_success`:

```
#!/bin/bash


if [ $1 == "history.log" ]
then

    echo "Changes in \"/var/log/apt/history.log\""

    if [ ! -f "/tmp/upgrade_success_last_run" ] || [ $(stat -c %Y "/tmp/upgrade_success_last_run") -lt $(date "+%s") ]
    then
        # look for changes since the last run
        # of this script ("upgrade_success")
        # in "/var/log/apt/history.log"
        # and make what you want.
    fi

    touch /tmp/upgrade_success_last_run

fi
```

### How to start app or script after system *update*

You write the following:

> ...
>   I would like to start my script after or during every Ubuntu
>   update.
>   ...

---

Create this file:

```
/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/16my-script
```

and add this line:

```
APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success {"<path_to_your_script> 2>/dev/null || true";};
```

*Unfortunately, there is no way to do the same for Upgrade, eg.:*

```
APT::Upgrade::Post-Invoke-Success {"<path_to_your_script> 2>/dev/null || true";};
```

---

OR

---

In the file `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/15update-stamp`

you can find this line:

```
APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success {"touch /var/lib/apt/periodic/update-success-stamp 2>/dev/null || true";};
```

Therefore you can watch for changes of the file `/var/lib/apt/periodic/update-success-stamp`. After any *update* command, even through *Software Updater*, this file's modification date is the date of the last successful *update*.

Watch the folder `/var/lib/apt/periodic/` with `inoticoming`:

```
sudo inoticoming /var/lib/apt/periodic/ upgrade {} \;
```

Script `upgrade`:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $1 == "update-success-stamp" ]
then
    sudo apt-get upgrade
fi
```

And also here: *Unfortunately, there is no way to do the same for Upgrade, eg.:*

```
APT::Upgrade::Post-Invoke-Success {"touch /var/lib/apt/periodic/upgrade-success-stamp 2>/dev/null || true";};
```

and watch for changes of the file `/var/lib/apt/periodic/upgrade-success-stamp`.

Comment: **@PeterMaciejko:** As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)
**A.B.:** Good one!  Upvoted!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by adding a say `upgrade` alias to `~/.bashrc`, and by running the alias to perform the upgrade:

1. Mark your script as executable: `chmod +x <path_to_script>`

<sub>*<path_to_script> = path to the script you want to run</sub>

2. Add an `upgrade` alias to `~/.bashrc`: `<<< "alias upgrade='sudo apt-get upgrade && <path_to_script>'" tee -a ~/.bashrc`

<sub>*<path_to_script> = path to the script you want to run</sub>

3. Update `~/.bashrc`: `. ~/.bashrc`

This way every time you run `upgrade` both `sudo apt-get upgrade` and your script will be executed, the script only upon success of `sudo apt-get upgrade`.